# Solr Throwing Error while full import( with clean option = false)

Tags: solr, dih

My problem is that when I am full-importing solr( via DIH ), when solr starts to fetch documents from MySql, if I query anything on that particular time I am getting a Server error like below

Note: While running Fullimport ( clean option is set to false)

```
HTTP Status 500 - For input string: "solr" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "solr" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441) at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483) at 
org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.readableToIndexed(TrieField.java:295) at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.toInternal(TrieField.java:307) at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.getFieldQuery(FieldType.java:580) at org.apache.solr.search.SolrQueryParser.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParser.java:201) at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1436) at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1319) at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1245) at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1234) at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:206) at
```

Please if somebody knows why its happening and how we can avoid this ?

*PS : Master & Slave replication can avoid this, but I indeed need without any replication.*

Comment: It clearly says numberformatexception. Your database would have some string data as "solr" which you are trying to insert into tint field type.

Comment: @swaraj thanks. Nope its indexing only , I get this error while indexing if I try to query to solr.Once its indexed I get no such errors

Comment: i tried to reproduce the same scenario in my solr cloud, but I didn't get any exception.

Comment: @swaraj what option did you tried , while full importing ?

Comment: command=full-import&clean=false&commit=true&optimize=true

Comment: Its strange ... I am too running with this options , but I get the above errors

Comment: I tried with both in single node mode and solr cloud mode also. may be you are missing something in configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74335/discussion-between-anirban-n-and-swaraj).